# rails render another controller action in js after destroy

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, render

I'm executing this code in clipsController:

```
  def destroy
    @clip = Clip.find(params[:id])
    @clip.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to request.referer, notice: "Attachment deleted."}
      format.js {
        @pmdocument = @clip.attachable
        render action: "pmdocuments/show"
      }
    end
  end
```

This should render a template called show.js.erb located in pmdocuments but instead, I get this error msg:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template clips/pmdocuments/show,
application/pmdocuments/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html]
, :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a leading `/`.  Its trying to render an action relative to the current controller. So this -

```
render action: "/pmdocuments/show"
```